# How I can create an opportunity in vTiger from Web Service

Tags: web-services, vtiger

I have a tiny task, its about of create an opportunity from Web Service on vTiger, I want to know Which are the basic parameters or commodities in order to send information.

And Which is the webservice to Opportunities

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you need to look into the creation of a Lead. Show your code if you need specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get list of webservices using jquery and PHP, maybe someone else could find this information important, in order to use the method is necessary be login, this action return a session_id + token (from application, user module) you can simulate the authentication and use the methods.

Good Lucky

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

[web service documentation](https://www.vtiger.com/docs/web-service-reference-manual)

Then look at the [tutorial](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials)

A good plan is to get your login and session working with your vtiger instance using the tutorial example, then use the "describe" example in the tutorial to get the XML schema for your opportunities module (including any fields you have added).

Once you have that schema, you can use it to create an opportunity XML object, and then post that using the web service create method.